# Python list index out of range, even after delimiting the indexes

Tags: python, arrays, list, range, index-error

In the code below I try to see if the next item of the given list is opposite to the previous one (i.e "North" & "South" or "East" & "West"). Of course, this will raise an IndexError once we reach the last item of the list. 
However, I have carefully delimited the for-loop so it stops before reaching the last index.

```
def dirReduc(arr):

for i in range(len(arr)-1):

    if arr[i] == "NORTH" and arr[i+1] == "SOUTH":
        arr.remove("NORTH"), arr.remove("SOUTH")

    elif arr[i] == "SOUTH" and arr[i+1] == "NORTH":
        arr.remove("SOUTH"), arr.remove("NORTH")

    elif arr[i] == "WEST" and arr[i+1] == "EAST":
        arr.remove("WEST"), arr.remove("EAST")

    elif arr[i] == "EAST" and arr[i+1] == "WEST":
        arr.remove("EAST"), arr.remove("WEST")

return arr
```

Could anyone please explain to my why this still raises `IndexError: list out of range`?

Here is a sample input: 
`["NORTH", "SOUTH", "SOUTH", "EAST", "WEST", "NORTH", "WEST"]`.

Comment: when you remove any value from the list .. it's length will decreases as well and that's why you're getting this error!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `range(len(arr) - 1)` returns a fixed object that is iterated over. The length of the array is not recalculated each iteration.

One possible solution is to copy all elements you don't want "removed" to another list.

Comment: This did the trick, thank you very much. I've now learned something important!

Answer (score 0):

Don't remove items from `list` while iterating over this (this is causing your error). You can try this idea:

```
def dirReduc(arr):
    expected_list = arr
    for i in range(len(arr) - 1):

        if arr[i] == "NORTH" and arr[i + 1] == "SOUTH":
            expected_list.remove("NORTH"), expected_list.remove("SOUTH")

        elif arr[i] == "SOUTH" and arr[i + 1] == "NORTH":
            expected_list.remove("SOUTH"), expected_list.remove("NORTH")

        elif arr[i] == "WEST" and arr[i + 1] == "EAST":
            expected_list.remove("WEST"), expected_list.remove("EAST")

        elif arr[i] == "EAST" and arr[i + 1] == "WEST":
            expected_list.remove("EAST"), expected_list.remove("WEST")

    return expected_list
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are remove the element from the list, then it continues looping through the list with non-updated len/range.
To avoid this, this ugly method can be used:

```
def dirReduc(arr):

    for i in range(len(arr)-1):
        if i >= len(arr):
            break
        if arr[i] == "NORTH" and arr[i+1] == "SOUTH":
            arr.remove("NORTH"), arr.remove("SOUTH")

        elif arr[i] == "SOUTH" and arr[i+1] == "NORTH":
            arr.remove("SOUTH"), arr.remove("NORTH")

        elif arr[i] == "WEST" and arr[i+1] == "EAST":
            arr.remove("WEST"), arr.remove("EAST")

        elif arr[i] == "EAST" and arr[i+1] == "WEST":
            arr.remove("EAST"), arr.remove("WEST")

    return arr
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the error is due to the second '`elif`', since if the `arr[i]` you are reading, matches the last element of your array, you can not consider the condition for the next element `arr[i + 1]`, as you are exceeding the length of your array.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because you are iterating over a list and removing elements during each iteration. In general, modifying the underlying object you are iterating over is dangerous and will lead to interesting bugs regardless of the language you are working in. As a beginning programmer, this is a practice you should avoid unless you have a very good reason to do it.

As was suggested, creating a copy of the underlying list and removing elements from the copy rather than the object you are iterating over is a good way to avoid this. If you do that, [make sure you do it correctly](http://henry.precheur.org/python/copy_list.html).

As another possible solution, consider using a dictionary to map each direction to its opposite:

```
opposite = { "NORTH": "SOUTH", "SOUTH": "NORTH", "EAST": "WEST", "WEST": "EAST" }
```

Now when you iterate over the list, you can do

```
def consolidate_directions(direction_list):
    directions = []
    # iterating over enumerate(iterable) is like iterating 
    # over iterable except it gives you access to both the current 
    # iteration count and the current item being processed on each iteration
    for i, direction in enumerate(direction_list):
        # this is a trick to avoid out of bounds error when checking for
        # the last element of the list. % is the modulus operator that returns 
        # 0 if the right hand side divides the left hand side evenly. In this 
        # case that would signify the first element of the list, meaning the 
        # current element is the last 
        last_index = (i - 1) % len(direction_list)
        next_index = (i + 1) % len(direction_list)
        if next_index == 0:
            return directions
        else:
            if not (direction_list[next_index] == opposite[direction]) \
             and not (direction_list[last_index] == opposite[direction]):
                directions.append(direction)
    return directions
```

More general feedback: most Python programmers use snake-case for function names (as I did above) instead of camel-case. Also, one of the perks of Python as a language is that it is highly readable -- it can read almost like English. Feel free to use highly descriptive names for your variables and functions. This makes your code easier to read and understand for other programmers, and easier for yourself to read and understand later.

This is nicely covered in the [PEP-8 Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which you should try follow as closely as possible while programming in Python.

Answer (score 0):

```
def dirReduc(arr):
    if len(arr)-1>0:
       num=  len(arr)-1
       for i in range(num):
           if arr[i] == "NORTH" and arr[i+1] == "SOUTH":
               arr[i]="error", arr[i+1]="error"

           elif arr[i] == "SOUTH" and arr[i+1] == "NORTH":
               arr[i]="error", arr[i+1]="error"
           elif arr[i] == "WEST" and arr[i+1] == "EAST":
               arr[i]="error", arr[i+1]="error"
           elif arr[i] == "EAST" and arr[i+1] == "EAST":
               arr[i]="error", arr[i+1]="error"
    return arr

def main(){
    arr=["EAST","EAST"]#just a example
    arrbuff=[]
    arrbuff.append(dirReduc(arr))#arrbuff is ["error","error"]
    newArr=[];#all correct direction
    for i in range(len(arrbuff)):
        if arrbuff[i] == "error" :
            print("what the error u set hahaha")
        else:
            newArr.append(arrbuff) 
}
```